# Can't update to Fedora 24?

Tags: linux, fedora, updates

I'm trying to upgrade my Fedora 23 instance to Fedora 24, and I'm following Fedora's [instructions](https://fedoramagazine.org/upgrading-fedora-23-workstation-to-fedora-24/).

When I type `sudo dnf system-update reboot`, my computer reboots. It loads as usual, with the little Fedora bubble filling up. The bubble becomes empty again, which is normal when updating. It displays a message in the upper left corner of the screen - `Starting system upgrade. This will take a while.` Without the bubble filling up at all, a few minutes later a message flashes on the screen, too quickly for me to read it. My computer reboots. Then boots into Fedora 23.

I don't want Fedora 23. I want Fedora 24.

I've tried redownloading the packages and running the reboot command again. Multiple times. I haven't found any similar problems online.

Could anyone help?

Edit: @Argonauts told me to post a log, so here it is: https://gist.github.com/TheInitializer/d73d438d16e98e5dfdcd8d0d006c88f9

Here are the commands I used to generate them:

```
david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log
The following boots appear to contain upgrade logs:
1 / 73147b7ed9b0437b82646d6bc1040153: 2016-06-22 18:46:43 23→24
2 / f8cfca577cff4835b77972e0299c4e21: 2016-06-22 19:06:08 23→24
3 / c340dd4b1144402c995eba28bde6350c: 2016-06-22 19:19:06 23→24
4 / a729395edcfa405fb2ce3a7781370549: 2016-06-22 19:24:33 23→24
5 / e20e4e7a52ce40278ea94d6daac84890: 2016-06-22 19:52:38 23→24
6 / d223201a2a5c4f8ebcb23aa62fde34f4: 2016-06-22 20:03:53 23→24
7 / 741ddd9b55a04f868c943e303efb8983: 2016-06-22 20:27:40 23→24
8 / fc8a838a99d644468df5ec62c97ad5de: 2016-06-22 20:58:58 23→24
9 / 34412677294b4b8191b71c66cbfe1782: 2016-06-22 21:07:13 23→24
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 1 > log1.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 2 > log2.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 3 > log3.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 4 > log4.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 5 > log5.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 6 > log6.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 7 > log7.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 8 > log8.txt
 david  ~  dnf system-upgrade log 9 > log9.txt
 david  ~ 
```

Comment: Info on the failed upgrade can be found in your system log, using `journalctl` dnf also provides an interface to journalctl to help isolate the upgrade event.  Run `dnf system-upgrade log` to see a list of boots during which an upgrade was attempted. Use `dnf system-upgrade log [NUM]`, where [NUM] is usually -1, to see the logs for that boot. Assuming you followed their instructions entirely, in order to have any idea what happened you'll have to post logs of the failure(s). Did you run `dnf distro-sync` prior to the upgrade?

Comment: @Argonauts Yes, I ran `dnf distro-sync` a few times. Here are my logs https://gist.github.com/TheInitializer/d73d438d16e98e5dfdcd8d0d006c88f9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is due to a conflict with a package from fc23, excerpt starting around line 4300:

```
dnf[871]: fontconfig-infinality-ultimate x86_64 2.11.94-4.fc23           @infinality-ultimate 990 k
dnf[871]: Error: Transaction check error:
dnf[871]: file /etc/fonts/conf.d/README from install of fontconfig-2.11.94-6.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package fontconfig-infinality-ultimate-2.11.94-4.fc23.i686
dnf[871]: file /etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf from install of fontconfig-2.11.94-6.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package fontconfig-infinality-ultimate-2.11.94-4.fc23.i686
```

The font package from the infanality repo overwrites a bunch of system font files when installed, and dnf is getting hung up on. I'll provide a few things to try - basically ordered on the 'what could wrong' scale.

**1**  The first thing to try is to check to see what would happen if you were to uninstall `fontconfig-infinality-ultimate-2.11.94-4.fc23.i686`. Try:

```
sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf remove fontconfig-infinality-ultimate-2.11.94-4.fc23.i686
```

and see what the response is. If it tells you it also needs to      uninstall a large number, e.g. 50, 100, 200+ other packages, select N. If all of the packages it is telling you need to uninstall are i686 and/or from third party repos, you should be good to go. Anything marked as from the std fedora repo or the fedora updates repo is sign to probably not continue - post the list if you are unsure.

If it uninstalls cleanly, then you are all set - the upgrade should go smoothly.

**2** Next try to install the fedora 23 version of the package that is preventing the install. Use the first command first; if that fails try the next one. Use the same common sense approach - if it tells you it needs to uninstall 200 packages, don't do it. It should try to install [this](ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/releases/23/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/f/fontconfig-2.11.94-4.fc23.x86_64.rpm).
If it can't find it, download it and provide the path to the rpm to the command instead of just fontconfig.

```
sudo dnf install fontconfig

sudo dnf install fontconfig --allowerasing
```

If this works, it should uninstall the infinality package - and the upgrade will go smooth.

**3** Last thing I can suggest without seeing the results from the previous steps (assuming they failed) is to do a distro sync that allows erasing. This might fail or might require a bunch of packages to be removed - it shouldn't be too bad, but take a good look before saying 'Y' to continue when prompted:

```
sudo dnf distro-sync --allowerasing
```

If none of this works posts your results from each command.

Sometimes there are other problems hidden behind the current problem - it's possible the update will fail for a different reason if you remove the currently conflicting package - check the same logs and see / post what the issue was if it does happen.

Comment: thanks so much, I'm running these command right now to see if they help.

Comment: Removing fontconfig-infinality-whatever wanted to remove 196 packages, including xterm, wxPython, every wine package, systemd-libs, readline, and a bunch of apps I use. How about... no.

Comment: Did you go past step 1? I was actually pretty close in my guesstimate.

Comment: yeah I'm on step 2

Comment: Ooh, installing fontconfig through dnf is installing a package called fontconfig (actually two, i386 and x86_64), and removing two packages called fontconfig-infinality-ultimate (also i386 and x86_84). This looks like it'll work!

Comment: Ran the command and it replaced that package, now re-running the installation commands. If it works I'll mark this as the answer, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Downloading 2494 packages. Again. D:

Comment: It worked, thank you so much from Fedora 24!